# Got "is not a recognized Objective-C method" when bridging Swift to React-Native

Tags: objective-c, swift, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to bridge my React-Native 0.33 code to a super simple Swift method, following [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) but all I'm getting is `show:(NSString *)name is not a recognized Objective-C method`.

Here's my code:

#### SwitchManager.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc(SwitchManager)
class SwitchManager: NSObject {

  @objc func show(name: String) -> Void {
    NSLog("%@", name);
  }

}
```

#### SwitchManagerBridge.h

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(SwitchManager, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(show:(NSString *)name)

@end
```

#### SwitchManager-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

Then on my `index.ios.js` file I'm importing SwitchManager with `import { SwitchManager } from 'NativeModules';` and calling `SwitchManager.show('One');`. This is where the error happened.

Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: how about `import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var SwitchManager = NativeModules.SwitchManager;`?

Comment: @VojtaNovak I think I tried this too, but it didn't work. I know SwitchManager.show is defined, because I did a `console.dir` and it's exposed.

Comment: @VojtaNovak just tried, same.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is a part of Swift 3's changes and can be solved by adding an underscore:

```
import Foundation

@objc(SwitchManager)
class SwitchManager: NSObject {

  @objc func show(_ name: String) {
    NSLog("%@", name);
  }

}
```

See Swift 3's [0046 Proposal: Establish consistent label behavior across all parameters including first labels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md) that is called out in the [Swift.org migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) under "Consistent first argument labels".

Basically, how Objective-C sees Swift methods has changed with Swift 3.

**EDIT: This is still the case in Swift 4, [see docs here under Omitting Argument Labels](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).**

Comment: This did it for me. I can confirm this is working with Swift 3 and React Native 0.34.0-rc.0.

Comment: Another note on this:  my method has 3 parameters and so I added the underscore for each of them.  This did not work!  You must add it to _only_ the non-labeled parameters

Comment: Yup, the main goal if you look at the docs is to keep compatibility with Obj-C libraries. Apple is likely going to be trying to phase this out entirely over time—in fact, swift-only functions don't require this underscore behavior. Reason why it comes up here is React Native is all Obj-C.

Comment: excellent! whats going on with that weird underscore? can someone shed some light?

Comment: See the link I put above for Apple's 0046 Proposal. It's basically because Objective C can have unnamed first arguments, but Swift now has named first arguments across the board. This underscore just keeps compatibility with existing libraries by having an explicit "unnamed" argument.

Comment: This also works for me. React native version 0.46.0 and swift 3, xcode 8.3.

Comment: Yup... if it matters, confirmed still working for me in my production app code underneath a React Native app. It's not an issue with RN regardless, since this is a Swift 3 standard. Confirmed, btw, that this will continue to be the case in Swift 4: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Comment: tnx, it works. it is still a case in Swift4 and xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Awesome Thanks

Comment: May be a different error, @Kartiikeya? At least for this specific issue, seems to still be necessary/the case for my code.

Comment: @GeorgeSalamanca Yes? This is now pretty fundamentally in Swift. If anything, it's more relevant given the changes in Swift 4 (though this matters more for native code): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated. One day, it won't be when React Native itself is written in swift, but until then...

Answer (score 22):

this worked for me in xcode 8.0 and swift 3

```
@objc func openPresentedViewController(_ name: String,name1: String,name2: String){
}
```

add `_` to non labelled members

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(methodName:(NSString *)name name1:(NSString *)name1 name2:(NSString *)name2)
```

as you can see in the objective c method name is nonlabeled parameter add `_` to it in the swift method

Comment: Worked for Swift 5 also.

Comment: For me it didn't worked.  I need to modify @objc declaration  to

@objc(openPresentedViewController: name1: name2:)

Comment: Worked for me as well for swfit 5.

Answer (score 3):

I was fighting with this issue all day. Resolved by setting the Swift Compiler to use Legacy versions (XCode 8 is prefers Swift 3), so in:

**Build Settings** > Scroll down to '**Use Legacy Swift Language Version**' set as **Yes**.

Comment: Does this mean you can't use Swift 3? I'm running into this issue as well, but I would like to use Swift 3 if possible.

Comment: @mike-cole Take a look at below. If you've been having trouble, see if the underscore makes a difference since that's a change in Swift 3 for compatibility with ObjC methods. It isn't the cause of everyone's problems (I landed here due to a different "is not a recognized Objective-C method" issue), but I'd guess this is a common one.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer, this is just a workaround. The solutions below about method labels are the actual solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error because I had forgotten to put the decorator @objc before the function declaration