# #selector not working in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to setup a timer in Xcode 9 using Swift 4 and I have a function called: hello.

So in the timer code, I added #selector(hello()) like I would before, but this time it would continue to crash and make me add @objc in front of the hello function. Does anyone know what that means? Thanks!

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44379348/6541007) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390378/6541007).

Answer (score 2):

When you use the selector expression `#selector` and pass in a function without parameters you'll need to call it like that `#selector(hello)`