# The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4

I have gone through with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated) and it is working but for `Alamofire`, it shows the same warning. How to get ride of it.

**UPDATE**

Alamofire Version 4.5.1

[image: Alamofire Dependency Analysis Warning]

Comment: Update your Alamofire library for Swift 4.0.

Comment: Did update with 4.5.1, though its shows same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, i took reference in my question.. Please go through it. @MiguelIsla

Comment: Well, Its working after updating Valid setting in xcode.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra sorry, didn't see the link :O