# "No targets to convert found" when trying to convert to current Swift syntax

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I have searched quite a bit and can't seem to find an answer for this specific problem. 
I have a project that is a bit older and written in Swift 2. I am trying to convert it to Swift 4, by going to "Edit > Convert > To current Swift Syntax..."

It opens a modal, which is blank inside, at the top says: "No targets to convert found."

I have tried messing around with it, just can't seem to figure this out. Any help is appreciated! [Screenshot of what I get here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlGtL.png)

Comment: Check the "Swift Language Version" build setting for the target; if it's "Swift 4", then change it to "Swift 3.2" and that should let you run the migration (compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/47210873/2976878).

Comment: oh wow - perfect! That fixed it exactly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yup. I think the problem for me was I set the project to 4.2 before doing the conversion. I think setting the project to a lower version than the "convert too" version make it available.

Answer (score 3):

Use Xcode 10.1 to convert swift 3.0 to swift 4.2, then use Xcode 11.2 to convert swift 4.2 to swift 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Swift version manually in the target Build settings and after try the Edit/convert option, then Xcode doesn't find any target to convert.