# Bridging Swift Initialisers to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm attempting to slowly migrate an Objective C app over to Swift and have started to create new classes -

```
public class MapsAPI : NSObject {

    let delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate

    public init(managerWithDelegate delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

}
```

Now in my Objective C `.m` file I've declared `#import MyTarget-Swift.h` and in my `.h` I've added `@class MapsAPI` which all seems fine however I'm not sure what the Objective C initialisation code should look like. I've tried -

```
MapsAPI *api = [[MapsAPI alloc] initWithManagerWithDelegate: self];
```

But that errors with -

> No visible @interface for 'MapsAPI' declares the selector
>   'initWithManagerWithDelegate:'

I've tried looking at the definition of my `MyTarget-Swift.h` but all that shows is -

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC4What7MapsAPI")
@interface MapsAPI : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
@end
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to add @objc to all methods which are to be exposed to Objective-C. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210873/bulk-fix-hundreds-of-selector-not-exposed-to-objective-c-errors-in-xcode-9-or  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762460/swift-4-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may choose to add `@objcMembers` to your class declaration:

```
public class @objcMembers MapsAPI : NSObject {

    let delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate

    public init(managerWithDelegate delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

Alternatively (or additionally... who am I to judge) you can mark your initializer as being exposed to Objective-C

```
public class MapsAPI : NSObject {

    let delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate

    @objc public init(managerWithDelegate delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

And if you want to, you can also explicitly define the Objective-C selector used:

```
public class MapsAPI : NSObject {

    let delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate

    @objc(initManagerWithDelegate:)
    public init(managerWithDelegate delegate: MapsAPIResponseDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought public classes and methods were automatically available to Objective-C from the auto-generated bridging header?