# Search a dictionary in a custom object inside an array

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I’m building search functionality. I have an array of User objects and each User has a dictionary of tags. I’m trying to return users with searched tags.

My user class is:

```
class User: NSObject { 
   var name: String? 
   var tags = Dictionary<String, String>() 
}
```

An example of the tags is:

```
tags: { 
    “entry1” : “test1”, 
    “entry2” : “test2”, 
    “entry3” : “test3” 
}
```

I’ve been trying variances of:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: “tags contains[c] %@", “test1”); 
 let filteredArray = self.usersArray!.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) };  print(“users = ,\(filteredArray)");
```

It’s throwing “this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tags.’ I'm not sure how to search inside the User object.

**Update**:
I've change the dictionary to an array and 
`filter { $0.tags.contains(searchTerm) }` works for exact search match, as suggested.

`.filter( {$0.tags.reduce(false, {$1.contains(searchTerm)} )} )` does not work for a partial match however, which is what i'm looking for.

Here is what is printed:

```
Search term: ale
Result: []
Tags array inside each object:
["Alex", "Will", ""]
["Bob", "Dan", ""]
["First", "Second", "Third"]
["Testing 1", "Testing 2", ""]
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us your `User` object too and how the tags are stored in them.

Comment: @DanielShaffer add the information to your question.

Comment: If you want to use NSPredicate then, as the error message suggests, you need to make the key 'tags" key-value-coding (KVC) compliant. See for example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47701737/1852207

Comment: why don't you just use a simple filter?
self.usersArray!.filter { $0.tags.values.contains(where: { $0 == "test1" }) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of tags seems cumbersome. Here is a simpler one.

```
class User {
    var name: String
    var tags: [String]
}
```

Now let's say you have an array of users in `users`.

```
var users: [User]

// Store users in the array
```

Now, this is how you check which user contains a particular tag.

```
let tag = "yourTag"

users.filter( { $0.tags.contains(tag) } )
```

However, if you are adamant that you need the tags in a **dictionary**, then you could do it like this,

```
users.filter( {$0.tags.values.contains(tag)} )
```

If you want to check if the tag is **part** of any of the tags in a particular user, you could do it like this,

```
let filteredUsers = users.filter( {$0.tags.reduce(false, {$1.contains(tag)} )} )
```

---

P.S - we don't use `;` in Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion. There is a reason it needs to be stored in the dictionary. Since this is the case, is there a way to still search it? Thanks,

Comment: @DanielShaffer what is the reason? That code looks very redundant because your keys are always the array indices.

Comment: Users can add other types of tags, which the server parses based on special key names. I can see if the server can be changed, but for now I have to work in these constraints.

Comment: @DanielShaffer can you show us a real example? Btw the answer has been edited for the case of your dictionary.

Comment: My answer satisfies the condition, you can use `.filter` and `.enumerated()` to return the value and key for each element in your tags dictionary, then compare it to a search predicate.

Comment: Thanks very much. The filter worked. One question: .contains only returns when there is an exact match, instead of just containing the word. Is there a way to actually return when it contains part of the search word? Example: your in yourTag would return yourTag. Thanks

Comment: @DanielShaffer that goes against the whole concept of tags. What is the actual requirement?

Comment: It seems like tags should be wrapped into a struct with potential flags and properties on them. For the server they can be encoded differently but there is no need to keep server data model structure on the client.

Comment: @Sulthan i agree, but that still doesn't explain the partial match he is ok with for the tag. Seems to me like those aren't actually tags in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to make your models conform to `Codeable`:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var userId: UUID
    var name: String = ""
    var referenceTags: [String: String] = [:]
}


    // Create some users:
    let Bob = User(userId: UUID(), name: "Bob", referenceTags: ["tag1": "no", "tag2": "yes"])
    let Steve = User(userId: UUID(), name: "Steve", referenceTags: ["tag2": "no", "tag3": "no"])
```

Create an array of users to filter.

```
    let users:[User] = [Bob, Steve]
```

Get a search predicate or string from your Search bar or other.

```
    let searchPredicate = "yes"
```

Filter and iterate over tags for the required value.

```
    let results = users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
        for (key, _) in user.referenceTags.enumerated() {
            if (user.referenceTags[key] == searchPredicate) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
```