# Swift 3 @objc interference issue not being fixed :-(

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

Before this gets marked as duplicate, **I've already checked [The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated)**

I'm resuming development on app which I had been working on before Xcode 9 (with Swift 4) was released.

I'm getting the build time warning "The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Rushed" target."

I know how to turn on/off/default the build setting but even when I turn it on and then 'default' it, the warning is still appearing.

Scrolling through my files, there are no warnings/yellow triangles which could tell me where the issue is occurring and there's no 'Fix' button appearing.

Please help!

Comment: Are there other targets (a `...Tests` target for example)? The warning is displayed for each target individually.

Comment: @vadian I'm not sure I understand :-( Where should I look?

Comment: Select the project on the top of the project navigator and look at the targets. How many do you have?

Comment: @vadian Actually it's fine! I clicked on my project and then the `Target` section. It turns out that my app's @objc interference was on even though it was off in `Project` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on the project (the first thing in the massive drop-down list)
2. Click on the `Targets` section that appears
3. Search for the `Swift 3 @objc interference` section
4. Turn it `On` and fix any warnings/errors that pop up
5. Turn it to `Default` and your project should run without any issues

Comment: I have the same problem in XCode 10.1, it is a project I started before XCode 9. I get this one warning message whether the  'Swift 3 @objc interference' is set to Default, On or Off. It appears to make no difference to running the app. I am changing this setting in both Project and Target