# Ionic 3 - your app contains non-public api usage

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

i have a ionic 3 app that works with emulator android ios and it is publish on google store but when i tryed to upload on apple store it give me back "your app contains non-public api usage"

I'm trying to check all plugin list that may have caused the problem; different from an app I published several days ago are:
barcodescanner
call-number
email-composer
geolocation
leaflet

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Nome App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "call-number": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "0.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.1",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501857/non-public-api-usage-the-app-contains-one-or-more-corrupted-binaries?

Comment: after some research, i have only removed cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and installed again using @latest

Answer (score 0):

What version of cordova-ios are you using? I had the same error, after trying different things for a couple of days I deleted the plugins folder, then compiled for cordova-ios@4.5.5 and it worked.

ionic cordova platform add ios@4.5.5

Comment: after some research, i have only removed cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and installed again using @latest

Comment: Hey @MarcoFerretti could you please explain what you did exactly? I got the same error and I tried 
https://pastebin.com/HgdZk6WR
But it still gives me the App Store Connect Operation Error.

Comment: @ElDiabolo you need
remove plugin: ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser install again with@latest at the end. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@latest.