# Having trouble using lazy with a var in swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I am following the standford ios class for Fall 2017.  As the professor goes through the demo, I follow by inputting and running like he does.  He shows how using lazy with a var allows one to use the UIButton count for variable initialization.  When I add the lazy keyword, the error doesn't go away.  Thinking it was maybe an xcode update related problem, I downloaded someone else's version of the project and that project doesn't have the issue.  The code is below, any thoughts? :/

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
lazy var game = ConcentrationModel(numberOfPairsOfCards: (cardButtons.count + 1) / 2)


//Could have had var flipCount: Int = 0
//But it is inferred
var flipCount = 0 {
    didSet {
        flipCountLabel.text = "Flips: \(flipCount)"
    }
}

var emojiChoices = ["","","","","",""]

@IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]!


@IBOutlet weak var flipCountLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func touchCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
    flipCount += 1
    if let cardNumber = cardButtons.index(of: sender) {
        flipCard(withEmoji: emojiChoices[cardNumber], on: sender)
        print("cardNumber = \(cardNumber)")
    } else {
        print("chosen card was not in cardButtons")
    }
    print("agh!!! a ghost")
}


func flipCard(withEmoji emoji: String, on button: UIButton) {
    if button.currentTitle == emoji {
        button.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        button.setTitle(emoji, for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9999960065, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a lazy property which depends on the value of another property you have to use the closure syntax

```
lazy var game : ConcentrationModel = { 
     return ConcentrationModel(numberOfPairsOfCards: (self.cardButtons.count + 1) / 2) 
}()
```

Comment: It looks like I don't need the closure, but your example showing the use the keyword self helped.  I just added that to my code and it worked.  The example in the video and the downloaded example both didn't have the self keyword.  So still not sure my difference

Comment: I had another issue related to using [swift 4] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated).  After addressing that I now can even remove the self keyword.  Thanks for sending down the right path