# Using @objc in Swift 4 deprecated, but what to do?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

So since `@objc` is deprecated in Swift 4, I am getting a new error messages. This is one of them:

> tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] is deprecated and will be removed in
>   Swift 4; add explicit '@objc' to the declaration to emit the
>   Objective-C entrypoint in Swift 4 and suppress this message

I have search a bit, and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380886/9886916 - But when I change **Swift 3 @objc Inference** to **Default** the app crashes. This is because of the `tableView` lines I have. They looks like this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return players.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.gameLabel.text = self.players [indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {

            players.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }
    }
```

The app runs fine when I am using `@objc func ...` and set **Swift 3 @objc Inference** to **ON** but since it is deprecated, I guess I should not do this? Any tips or solutions here?

EDIT: This is the full error message:

> *** /Users/Me/Documents/XCODE/Prosjekter/MyProject/MyProject/JHACategoriesController.swift:116:5:
>   implicit Objective-C entrypoint -[MyProject.JHACategoriesController
>   tableView:heightForFooterInSection:] is deprecated and will be removed
>   in Swift 4; add explicit '@objc' to the declaration to emit the
>   Objective-C entrypoint in Swift 4 and suppress this message Current
>   stack trace: 0    libswiftCore.dylib
>
>   0x000000010ead0ff0 swift::warning(unsigned int, char const*, ...) +
>   228 1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x000000010eb075b0
>   swift_objc_swift3ImplicitObjCEntrypoint + 514 2    MyProject
>
>   0x0000000106288d20 @objc
>   JHACategoriesController.tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:) + 84 3 
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109aebf53 -[UITableView
>   _delegateWantsFooterForSection:] + 576 4    UIKit                              0x0000000109db4414 -[UISectionRowData
>   refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1236 5    UIKit
>
>   0x0000000109db92f1 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 95 6    UIKit 
>   0x0000000109ad2d7e -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 117 7
>
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109ad1d3f -[UITableView
>   reloadData] + 1354 8    MyProject
>
>   0x0000000106285ea0 JHACategoriesController.viewDidLoad() + 4879 9
>
>   MyProject                          0x0000000106287210 @objc
>   JHACategoriesController.viewDidLoad() + 36 10   UIKit
>
>   0x0000000109b3ecd2 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1215 11
>
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109b3f5b9
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27 12   UIKit                              0x0000000109b708bd -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] +
>   945 13   UIKit                              0x0000000109b87318
>   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 714 14   UIKit                              0x0000000109b88836
>   -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150 15   UIKit                              0x0000000109de0af0 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231 16
>
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109a6a21d
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515 17   QuartzCore                         0x000000010947a569 -[CALayer
>   layoutSublayers] + 177 18   QuartzCore
>
>   0x000000010947e6a0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 395
>   19   QuartzCore                         0x0000000109405148
>   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 343 20
>
>   QuartzCore                         0x0000000109432708
>   CA::Transaction::commit() + 568 21   UIKit
>
>   0x00000001099c3e7c _afterCACommitHandler + 272 22   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010e31e5f0
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23 23   CoreFoundation                     0x000000010e31e3b0
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430 24   CoreFoundation                     0x000000010e302580 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537 25   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010e302090 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635 26   GraphicsServices
>
>   0x000000010f9afa35 GSEventRunModal + 62 27   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010999b018 UIApplicationMain + 159 28   MyProject
>
>   0x00000001062baf10 main + 55 29   libdyld.dylib
>
>   0x000000011163c954 start + 1**
>    /Users/Me/Documents/XCODE/Prosjekter/MyProject/MyProject/JHACategoriesController.swift:59:5:
>   implicit Objective-C entrypoint -[MyProject.JHACategoriesController
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] is deprecated and will be removed in
>   Swift 4; add explicit '@objc' to the declaration to emit the
>   Objective-C entrypoint in Swift 4 and suppress this message Current
>   stack trace: 0    libswiftCore.dylib
>   0x000000010ead0ff0 swift::warning(unsigned int, char const, ...) +
>   228 1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x000000010eb075b0
>   swift_objc_swift3ImplicitObjCEntrypoint + 514 2    MyProject
>   0x00000001062877b0 @objc
>   JHACategoriesController.tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) + 84 3
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109b05813 -[UITableView
>   _numberOfRowsInSection:] + 62 4    UIKit                              0x0000000109db4414 -[UISectionRowData
>   refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2631 5    UIKit
>   0x0000000109db92f1 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 95 6    UIKit 
>   0x0000000109ad2d7e -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 117 7
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109ad1d3f -[UITableView
>   reloadData] + 1354 8    MyProject
>   0x0000000106285ea0 JHACategoriesController.viewDidLoad() + 4879 9
>   MyProject                          0x0000000106287210 @objc
>   JHACategoriesController.viewDidLoad() + 36 10   UIKit
>   0x0000000109b3ecd2 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1215 11
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109b3f5b9
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27 12   UIKit                              0x0000000109b708bd -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] +
>   945 13   UIKit                              0x0000000109b87318
>   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 714 14   UIKit                              0x0000000109b88836
>   -[UINavigationController **viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150 15   UIKit                              0x0000000109de0af0 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231 16
>
>   UIKit                              0x0000000109a6a21d
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515 17   QuartzCore                         0x000000010947a569 -[CALayer
>   layoutSublayers] + 177 18   QuartzCore
>
>   0x000000010947e6a0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 395
>   19   QuartzCore                         0x0000000109405148
>   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 343 20
>
>   QuartzCore                         0x0000000109432708
>   CA::Transaction::commit() + 568 21   UIKit
>
>   0x00000001099c3e7c _afterCACommitHandler + 272 22   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010e31e5f0
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23 23   CoreFoundation                     0x000000010e31e3b0
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430 24   CoreFoundation                     0x000000010e302580 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537 25   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010e302090 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635 26   GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010f9afa35 GSEventRunModal + 62 27   UIKit
>   0x000000010999b018 UIApplicationMain + 159 28   MyProject
>   0x00000001062baf10 main + 55 29   libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000011163c954 start + 1 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: "So since @objc is deprecated in Swift 4" It isn't, so your premise is false. In fact, in Swift 4 it is needed _more_ than in the past. However, it is not needed for table view delegate methods. Show the context in which you are putting these lines; it sounds like you may have forgotten to adopt UITableViewDataSource explicitly, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be mostly that you have not updated your method signatures. For example, you have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

That's wrong. It should be

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

And so on. Just walk thru all those declarations in the documentation or header and fix them to match the updated signatures.

Also make sure that this code is either in a UITableViewController or in a view controller that explicitly adopts UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

**EDIT** You have now posted your code (at https://pastebin.com/dxSM3SJw), and it shows clearly that you did not do what I said. Okay, I'm going to repeat it all. Please read *carefully* what I am saying.

Your view controller declaration is:

```
class JHACategoriesController: UIViewController {
```

That is the opposite of what I said to do. I said:

> Also make sure that this code is either in a UITableViewController or in a view controller that explicitly adopts UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

You didn't do that. Do it. You need this declaration to be:

```
class JHACategoriesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Then you need to fix all the delegate and data source methods to be the correct updated signature. You still have not done that, either. For example, the code you posted in pastebin has this declaration:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfSectionsInTableView indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
```

Thats wrong. The code you posted in your question has a different signature:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
```

But that's wrong too. The correct signature is:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
```

I assure you that when you fix these for all your delegate and data source methods, all your problems will go away.

Comment: What about the `heightForFooterInSection` and `numberOfRowsInSection`? I tried changing to the one listed in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview , but the app stil crashes on those two methods.

Comment: Sorry, I can rephrase what I'm writing so you understand: What is the updated method for `heightForFooterInSection ` and `numberOfRowsInSection `? I tried changing to the one in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview , but it doesn't work. Error message: `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:] is deprecated and will be removed in Swift 4; add explicit '@objc' to the declaration to emit the Objective-C entrypoint in Swift 4 and suppress this message
`

Comment: Well that is the message that displays when the app crashes, and `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` at the bottom

Comment: Oh sorry, updated the question with full error code, here is also the code: https://pastebin.com/6Fb9CXrd

Comment: Here you have it: https://pastebin.com/dxSM3SJw - I also have arrays for Blanding, Alle Spørsmål, Harmløs and Reise at the end of then project.

Comment: Okay, see my updated answer. You didn't do what my answer told you, so I repeated the key points.

Comment: Oh, I was mixing the two similar projects, your fix made it work. Thanks!