# Flutter build fails for iOS Xcode 10

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode10

I upgraded Flutter to latest. Following is the doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A326h, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.27.1)
```

When I run the app with target to iOS simulator, I get this

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XS Max in debug mode...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/kalehv/dev/todo/todo-flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/kalehv/dev/todo/todo-flutter/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/kalehv/dev/todo/todo-flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
    warning: The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target. (in target 'Runner')
    warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '/Users/kalehv/dev/todo/todo-flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' (in target 'Runner')
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XS Max.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would help at least it worked for me [url](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685).

Open your `Xcode` and there is `File` upper-left next to Apple icon, then open `Workspace Settings` and change the build system to `Legacy Build System`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Now I wish libimobiledevice fix new iPhone XS family UDID recognition.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but when I changed to `Legacy Build System` I got a ton of `Apple Mach-O Linker Error`'s instead.

I finally narrowed the problem down to a setting in `Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` (which can be manipulated from XCode in the Runner -> Build settings tab).

I had somehow set

```
Build active architecture only
           - Debug                   No
           - Profile                 Yes
           - Release                 Yes
```

Changing it to

```
Build active architecture only
           - Debug                   Yes
           - Profile                 Yes
           - Release                 Yes
```

solved the errors.

Comment: Mannnnnnnn.... Thanks alot. I've almost wasted 1.5 day. Thanks mattt.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this By uncommit platform target in the `Podfile` inside ios folder, So it will be 9.
Then you must change the platform target from Xcode to 9 this very important.
after that do this Open your Xcode and there is `File` upper-left next to Apple icon, then open Workspace Settings and change the build system to `Legacy Build System`.

then do this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379348/the-use-of-swift-3-objc-inference-in-swift-4-mode-is-deprecated)

Hit the `clean` button project in Xcode and run it.

I hope this will help you.