# Bridging Swift class to React Native after Swift 4.2 upgrade

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios, bridging-header

In Swift 3.0, I have the following Swift class

```
import Foundation

@objc(NetworkManager)
class NetworkManager: NSObject {


  init(...) {
    ...
  }


  deinit {
    ...
  }

  func isConnected(resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    ...
  }
}
```

And the following bridge:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(NetworkManager, NSObject)
  _RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_METHOD(isConnected, isConnectedWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject, NO)
@end
```

After upgrading to Swift 4.2, this begins to fail with `isConnnectedWithResolver:rejecter is not a recognized Objective-C method.`

After looking around and finding this question: [Got "is not a recognized Objective-C method" when bridging Swift to React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692230/got-is-not-a-recognized-objective-c-method-when-bridging-swift-to-react-native),
and this code sample: https://github.com/bigali/StringToHash/blob/master/ios/StringToHash/StringToHash.m

I've changed this to:

```
import Foundation

@objc(NetworkManager)
class NetworkManager: NSObject {


  init(...) {
    ...
  }


  deinit {
    ...
  }

  func isConnected(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    ...
  }
}
```

and:

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(NetworkManager, NSObject)
  _RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_METHOD(isConnected, isConnected:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject, NO)
@end
```

Which only changes the function name in the error message to:

```
isConnnectedWithResolver:rejecter is not a recognized Objective-C method.
```

Whats causinng this problem? Why is the solution outlined in the other questionn not working? And how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you declare `RCTPromiseRejectBlock` to be @objc?

Comment: how would I do that? I can't get rid of the @escapingn as I do need the promise (this being a JS promise) to survive the call to isConnected?

Answer (score 0):

You shold import eventEmitter to.
Put it into your header bridge file and in your objective-c files

```
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
```