# React native not a recognised objective C method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I am trying to bridge a call-back from native module to react native. I have tried this as well [Got "is not a recognized Objective-C method" when bridging Swift to React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692230/got-is-not-a-recognized-objective-c-method-when-bridging-swift-to-react-native)

I have added underscore to my first parameter as well

Following is my swift code

```
import Foundation
import LocalAuthentication

@objc(FingerPrintModule)
class FingerPrintModule: NSObject {
  
  var resultCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock!
  
  @objc func authenticateLocallyForIos(_ callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
    resultCallback = callback
    useLocalAuthentication()
  }
  
  private func useLocalAuthentication(){
    //Business logic
  }
  
}
```

I have created `objective c` file for my `swift` file as well

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(FingerPrintModule, NSObject)


RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(authenticateLocallyForIos: callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
 
@end
```

When I call from react native I get error saying not recognised `objective c` method

my React Native code

```
import { NativeModules,
  Platform,
} from "react-native";
const { FingerPrintModule } = NativeModules;
```

Called on button press

```
FingerPrintModule.authenticateLocallyForIos((err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
          Alert.alert(result.toString());
        } else {
          Alert.alert(err);
        }
      });
```

Comment: can you add React side code from where you calling this method.

Comment: @Daljeet check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change my `objective c` code to as follows

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(authenticateLocallyForIos:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

Answer (score 0):

In your react code do something like below:

```
const yourModule = NativeModules.FingerPrintModule;
```

And then call method like below:

```
yourModule.authenticateLocallyForIos((err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
          Alert.alert(result.toString());
        } else {
          Alert.alert(err);
        }
      });
```

Comment: @Dalijeet I tried your way and get same error. Actually my way is correct one as it works on Android but for iOS it gives error. There is some mistake in method definition of my swift or objective c file

Comment: can you try creating simple method RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(sayHello) without any param and print hello in it